# Disable triggers and re-enable triggers but avoid table alteration in meantime

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, locking

I have the following situation: 
A table (`MyTable`) should be processed (updates/inserts/deletes etc) by a batch process (a call to a `myplsql()` procedure).

During `myplsql` execution no one should touch `MyTable` - so `MyTable` is locked in exclusive mode by `myplsql`.

Now `MyTable` has a number of `on insert`,`on update`, `on delete` triggers defined but those are not needed while performing batch processing - moreover they slow down the batch process extremely.

So the solution is to disable the triggers before calling `myplsql()`.

But how to avoid someone touching the `MyTable` just after `alter table ... disable trigger` is performed and before  `myplsql` manages to lock the table,
given that  `alter table` performs implicit commit - so any lock acquired before that will be lost anyway?

Part of  the problem is that I do not control the other code  or the other user that could try to touch the Table.

In a few words I need to perform the following in a single shot:

```
Lock MyTable 
Disable Triggers (somehow without loosing the lock)
Process MyTable
Enable Triggers
Unlock MyTable
```

One thought was to remove grants from the table - and render it unusable for other users.

But as it is turns out -  that is not an option as the other processes/users perform their operations logged in as a table owner user.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slightly different approach is to keep the triggers enabled but reduce (if not quite entirely remove) their impact, by adding a `when` clause something like:

```
create or replace trigger ...
...
for each row
when (sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') is null
   or sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') != 'BATCH')
declare
...
begin
...
end;
/
```

Then in your procedure [add a call at the start](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.html) as your 'disable triggers' step:

```
dbms_application_info.set_client_info('BATCH');
```

and clear it again at the end, just in case the session is left alive and reused (so you might want to do this in an exception handler too):

```
dbms_application_info.set_client_info(null);
```

You could also use module, or action, or a combination. While that setting is in place the trigger will still be evaluated but won't fire, so any thing happening inside will skipped - the trigger body does not run, as [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html) put it.

This isn't foolproof as there is nothing really stopping other users/applications making the same calls, but if you pick a more descriptive string and/or a combination of settings, it would have to be deliberate - and I think you're mostly worried about accidents not bad actors.

---

Quick speed test with a pointless trigger that does just slows things down a bit.

```
create table t42 (id number);

-- no trigger
insert into t42 (id) select level from dual connect by level <= 10000;

10,000 rows inserted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.050

create or replace trigger tr42 before insert on t42 for each row
declare
  dt date;
begin
  select sysdate into dt from dual;
end;
/

-- plain trigger
insert into t42 (id) select level from dual connect by level <= 10000;

10,000 rows inserted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.466

create or replace trigger tr42 before insert on t42 for each row
when (sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') is null
   or sys_context('userenv', 'client_info') != 'BATCH')
declare
  dt date;
begin
  select sysdate into dt from dual;
end;
/

-- userenv trigger, not set
insert into t42 (id) select level from dual connect by level <= 10000;

10,000 rows inserted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.460

- userenv trigger, set to BATCH

exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info('BATCH');

insert into t42 (id) select level from dual connect by level <= 10000;

10,000 rows inserted.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.040

exec dbms_application_info.set_client_info(null);
```

There's a bit of variation from making remote calls, but I ran a few times and it's clear that running with a plain trigger is very similar to running with the constrained trigger without BATCH set, and both are much slower than running without a trigger or with the constrained trigger with BATCH set. In my testing there's an order of magnitude difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the idea and the detailed answer. I'll probably will go ahead with your solution. There is something confusing in your summary though  ... As I see it "plain trigger is very similar to running with the constrained trigger **without**  BATCH set, both are much slower than running without a trigger or with constrained trigger **with** BATCH set. don't you agree?