# Oracle: disable trigger before Insert

Tags: oracle, database-trigger

I'm trying to write a transaction on Oracle DBMS to make a "simple" insert.
In a single transaction I want **disable the trigger**, **make the Insert** and **re-enable the trigger**... I'm working with C# and Oracle Db Oracle Database 11g.....

Is it possible? 
How?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The documentation has a section on [trigger enabling and disabling](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-triggers.html#GUID-6CD799AB-FAEF-493A-8A58-2394E400072C)...

Comment: Thanks Alex! My question is not correct ... In the same transaction I want disable trigger, make the Insert and re-enable the trigger... Is it possibile?? I'm working with C# and Oracle Db Oracle Database 11g.....

Comment: Disabling and enabling a trigger are DDL, so they will implicitly commit. The disable will commit anything that has already happened, and the enable will commit the insert. If these combined actions are part of a larger transaction then you'll need to rethink this. Is this something you'll need to do often, and are you able to modify the trigger? You might be able to [use a context-level flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248894/266304) to control the trigger's behaviour, without having to disable it - which will affect all other sessions, not just the insert you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes I need to do it often and I am able to to modify the trigger ....

Comment: OK, then I'd suggest you look at using `client_info` or some other context item, set from your application before you do your insert, to control whether the trigger fires. As shown in the answer I linked to. As I said, disabling the trigger will affect everyone, as well as committing when you might not want to.

Comment: Sure, you just need to call `dbms_application_info.set_client_info()` or similar before you do the insert.

Comment: Now I'm not sure whether to close this as a duplicate... the other question was about locking, but the answer is essentially the same, and I don't want to just copy and paste that answer here. I'll leave it for wiser minds to decide.

Comment: Hi Alex! The dbms_application_info is the right way! Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

```
alter trigger trigger1 disable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE evaluations DISABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
ALTER TABLE evaluations ENABLE ALL TRIGGERS;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.