# Alter trigger from another trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, alter

I wish to have alter trigger under another trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER izmeni_naziv_kupac
AFTER UPDATE OF naziv ON Kupac
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    novi_naziv varchar2(255);
    pibK INT;    
BEGIN
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ZabranaPromeneNazivaKupaca DISABLE';

    pibK := :new.pib;
    novi_naziv := :new.naziv;
    
        UPDATE Porudzbina
        SET naziv_kupca = novi_naziv
    WHERE kupac_PIB = pibK;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TRIGGER ZabranaPromeneNazivaKupaca ENABLE';
END;
```

Problem is that system sent error message:

> ORA-04092: cannot COMMIT in a trigger
> ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.IZMENI_NAZIV_KUPAC", line 5
> ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.IZMENI_NAZIV_KUPAC'

Comment: It's helpful to state the real problem you're trying to solve; it looks like you want an update on `Porudzina` to not fire the trigger on that table, when that update is a side-effect of an update on `Kupac`? If so, and you can modify the other trigger, you could add a `when` to that which stops it firing based on context, maybe? ([Something like this, perhaps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51248894/266304))

Comment: Really problem is that I need to run this trigger and to disable/enabe previous one under this and not out of trigger. It is request by professor. No comment. I've solved by pragma autonomous_transaction but not sure whether it is OK. Thanks a lot. Another thrigger should avoid direct change on porudzbina while this should allow based on change in table Kupac. Crazy denormalization? Thanks a lot fro modification of my code, but I don't see why you changed title ( very imortant that we speak about Oracle) as well as tag sql-developer. In some other Oracle environment I don't have problem

Comment: If you must, then autonomous transaction is the only way to do it, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks a lot. OK, will use autonomous

Comment: What stops someone else updating a row in `Porudzina` during the period the trigger is disabled? And - if the whole second trigger is made autonomous - the update within that is independent of the triggering update on `Kupac`, which could still be rolled back. I really hope this isn't something your professor thinks is a good idea; it would be interesting to see the actual reuirement. (As to title... I added a *tag* for Oracle so that doesn't need to be in the title; and this is nothing to do with the SQL Developer *client*.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification, but all must be done in sql developer environment. And I am also confused with idea due after full normalization he asked for denormlization and also to create trigger which will avoid changes on denormalized db.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a practical way to manage trigger activation, and for the same reason, I'd advise against using 'autonmous' to work around it because its very rare to want to turn off a trigger for *all* users, because typically that breaks an application.

More likely is that you want to disable a trigger for this *current* session, for example, to perform some sort of maintenance activity etc. For this task, you would code the trigger to have a flag in order to let you control its execution.

Thus your code would be along the lines of (psuedo-code):

```
trigger my_trigger
before insert ...
begin
  if i_am_meant_to_fire then
     ...
     ... my normal code
     ...
  end if;
end;
```

where you then have session level control over when the trigger should take any action.  It is always enabled, but might not do anything based on the flag.

A full walkthrough of some options here

https://youtu.be/P1OFbNhgT1k